# Let $F$ denote the collection of all finite subsets of $[0, 1]$....

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ denote the collection of all finite subsets of $[0, 1]$ and let $F([0, 1], \mathbb{F})$ be
equipped with the topology $\tau_{T}$. Show that the continuous functions from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{F}$ are dense in $(F([0, 1], \mathbb{F}), \tau_{T})$ but that there is no sequence of continuous functions from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{F}$ converging to $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ given by

$f(t) :=1 ,{t} \notin {[0, 1] ∩ Q}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$
$f(t) :=0 ,{t} ∈ [0, 1] ∩ Q$

book: A Taste of Topology- Volker Runde- page 87.

Comment: What is $\Bbb F$? And what have you tried.

Comment: And once you've told us what $\mathbb F$ is, what's $F([0,1],\mathbb F)$? And what's $\tau_T$?

Comment: And, finally, what have you tried? Your question is simply a problem statement, without any hint of extra context that is expected on this site, such as: what you might have tried; where you got stuck, etc. Take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Ilya
 $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R} or \mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$